# Setting a button's text to have some bold characters in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, styles

I'd like to know if it is possible to define as the text of a `Button` in WPF, something like:
a **b** c

I've tried setting
[alt text http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/1838/ctldhrzhy41gbrcch4dpjz4.png](http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/1838/ctldhrzhy41gbrcch4dpjz4.png)

but that doesn't seem to work.

Is it only possible to use the `Bold` tag with `FlowDocument`s?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a `TextBlock` to hold the formatted text:

```
<Button>
  <TextBlock>Hey <Bold>you</Bold>!!!</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Per your comment, if you want to be explicit about the fact that this sets the `Content` property, you can use XAML property element syntax to do so:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Content>
    <TextBlock>Hey <Bold>you</Bold>!!!</TextBlock>
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

However this is redundant because `Button` has a `ContentPropertyAttribute` which makes the first version exactly equivalent to the second anyway.

Comment: Perfect! That'll do the job. Now, is any way to put it inside Contents? Not that I need it, just trying to understand what is going on here.

Comment: No.  An attribute can only hold plain text.

Comment: The only way to do what you want is as posted. When you use the Content property, its the same as setting the text in the old WinForms.

Comment: Yes, but only using XAML property element syntax.  I've updated the answer to show how, but to reiterate, it's redundant to do so: a child element of a Button automatically becomes its Content anyway.

Comment: Can this be done in the same way in VS2017 ; please help as I am unable to do so

Answer (score 12):

This will work.

```
<Grid>
   <Button Name="button1" Width="40" Height="40" 
           Content="something" FontWeight="Bold" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `<Button><TextBlock>a<Bold>b</Bold>c</TextBlock></Button>`.

Answer (score -1):

The simpliest solution i could think of:

```
 private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     string buttonText = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
 }
```